# Chrome Extension to modify images of loaded web pages

Tags: html, google-chrome

[image: I wish to edit image on this web page]

Is there any chrome extension or trick so that I can change the image on a loaded web page? 
Some extensions like *page edit* can modify only the text not the images. I want to add a image from my PC to the web page

Comment: How about this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-replacer/kjdfnmkplcjchfjealepndkfjgcgonib?hl=en ?

Comment: But if you upload images on a server so you can access them via HTTP rather than fia file, you could inspect the element and change the src of the img tag.